# Slack slash command to open external URL for google form

Tags: google-forms, slack, slack-api

I have a google form that already integrates a webhook for responses to populate in  a certain channel. What I want to do is incorporate a slack slash command to open that form in slack for the users to fill out. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

What I have done so far:

- implemented the slash command but dont know how to incorporate how to GET the url for the form to show
- Have a google script active for the webhook to send responses to the slack channel

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly trigger the opening of an external URL in the browser with a slash command from Slack. I talked with the Slack support team about such a feature some time ago and they had too many security concerns.

But you have other options. Just reply with a message to the slash command and include a direct link to your google form for the user to click on (e.g. `<https://www.google.com/|Google>`) or show a [link button](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attaching_link_buttons_to_a_message).